# Rails Wicked Form: Stop others changing object values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

When creating an object with partial validations like [here](http://brains.rabid.co.nz/2014/09/29/rails-multistep-forms.html), Wicked requires the object id in the url -

```
http://localhost:3000/pets/1/steps/identity
```

Does this mean that anyone can type this route and modify the data?

I need the form to be filled in by anyone (not logged in), but I don't want there to be any access by a third party to another users object.

I only need to create a simple multistep form like [here](https://www.johnsoncleaners.com/johnsons-bridal/new-order/), which allows standard back and forward button functionality.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need an authorisation check of some sort. The Wicked Form gem doesn't handle that stuff.

Try [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). It's pretty solid and the code is clean. The README is easy to follow and shows you how to add a check to each controller action that will only allow the people you choose to edit.

In your case, you would want the following inside the `Ability` class:

```
can [:new, :create], Pet
can [:edit, :update], Pet, user: user
```

Showing that anyone can make a new pet, but you can only load and submit the edit form if the pet is yours.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but does cancancan only work with checks against a logged in user?

Comment: No, you can use it for non-logged in users too, Just assume that `user` is nil and don't use it as in the first line of code above. then make a block starting with `if user` and put the ones for the logged in users inside.

Comment: Thanks again Matt but I don't think it'll work, this form will never need to be used by a logged in user. It's just a standard form that I want anyone to be able to fill in.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, you can create temporary ones something like this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Comment: A fantastic thanks I'll check that out, I was wondering if it was possible with standard server sessions.